# Get last character in javascript string ignoring whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Given string:

`234 +` (note the space after `+`)

I want to write a function that determines if there was one of certain characters there (in this case `+`)

**Background**

I have an input to hold a mathematics equation

I want to have buttons that can add 2-digit, 3-digit numbers etc. While also allowing the user to type in their own numbers and operators.

So if the input is empty, and the user clicks the 3-digit button, I want `234`to be added to the input.

If he clicks again, I want to add `+ 234` (as there is no operator there)

Now, if the user types another `+` (optionally followed by any amount of spaces), I want to add only `234` again

**tldr**

How can i read the last non-whitespace character in a string?
jquery preferred, vanilla is also ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First trim off any whitespace, then just get the last character and compare it to something

```
var str = "234 + ";

str = str.trim();

var last = str.charAt(str.length - 1);
```

Comment: trim not remove whitespace between string

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN - no, it removes whitespace from the start, and the end, of strings, which is enough here

Answer (score 4):

```
.(?=\s*$)
```

- `.` - a character
- `(?=)` - positive lookahead to verify the existence of, but not include in the match
- `\s*` - zero or more spaces
- `$` - til the end of the string

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/tM7pZ6/1)

Comment: thanks, looks nice. but i think adeneo's answer is a bit more verbose

Comment: `str = '234 + '; re = /(\S)(?=\s*$)/; lastNonSpaceSymbol = str.match(re)[0];`

Comment: can you expand this one to also match `sqrt(234)`? then, this will be my answer  edit: never mind.. on second thought, i don't even have to match that, because it's not an operation. if there was a sqrt(234), i can just go on with adding `+` as if it was a normal number

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/zV5zV2/1

```
str = '234 +   \n 823 + sqrt(4)       \n 7880 - cos(16)\t'
re = /(\S)+(?=\s*$)/gm
lastWords = str.match(re)
console.log(lastWords)  //logs ["+", "sqrt(4)", "cos(16)"]
```

Input string is multiline to illustrate different possibilities.